# How to generate random data having multiple peaks using numpy or scipy?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am working on fitting curves in x-ray diffraction plot. I need to generate random data to test my program. The features of the random data should be:

- That it should have multiple peaks.
- The peak heights should be variable.
- Should have some noise.

I am linking to a photo showing what kind of plot I need:

[image: Plot]

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What about using [numpy.random.normal](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.normal.html) with different means and standard deviations and summing several normal distributions with some baseline noise?